# Append an Element Child on a DOM middle of a DOM document Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I've got two same Documents and I'd like to append one or more elements from a document to anotehr. However, when I do this I'm getting errors like "Null Exception"

The XML are the same syntax like the example below:

```
<var1 code="1">
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="67" attribute3="SP-5046"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="63" attribute3="SP-5042"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="62" attribute3="SP-5041"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="61" attribute3="SP-5040"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="48" attribute3="SP-5027"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="47" attribute3="SP-5026"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="46" attribute3="SP-5025"/>
</var1>
<var1 code="1">
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="67" attribute3="SP-5046"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="63" attribute3="SP-5042"/>
<elementVar1 attribute1="0" attribute2="46" attribute3="SP-5025"/>
</var1>
```

The Java Code is written like this:

```
// docCurrent and docNew is already filled with the same syntax
NodeList nlC = docCurrent.getElementsByTagName("elementVar1");
NodeList nlN = docNew.getElementsByTagName("elementVar1");
Element elementNew = (Element)nlN.item(3);
Element element = (Element)nlC.item(1);
element.getParentNode().appendChild(elementNew); // The error Null Exception occurrs here
```

Is there any differente way to get the element from a doc and append it in the another doc ?

Comment: are you sure element and element.getParentNode() are not null?

Comment: I'm Totally sure. When I debugged I could see it's not null. However, I tried it without getParentNode() like (element.appendChild(elementNew) and then I received another error: "DOM cant have 2 root something like this"

Comment: I see. try http://www.coderanch.com/t/561569/XML/Appending-data-existing-XML-file

Comment: And http://sevalapsha.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/copy-nodes-xml-documents-java-dom/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try some of them and let you know if it worked

Comment: Leo, I found another site [LINK CLICK HERE](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/dom/copy-nodes-subtree-from-one-dom-document-to-another/) that worked! Thanks a lot without you help I wouldn't have fixed it

Comment: you`re welcome. Please post (and accept) your own answer, so  your question will help other people here ;-)

Comment: Sure thing I'll do this. I have to wait 24 hours first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I managed to append an element child to another DOM tree.

```
NodeList nlC = docCurrent.getElementsByTagName("elementVar1");
NodeList nlN = docNew.getElementsByTagName("elementVar1");
Element elementNew = (Element)nlN.item(3);
Node copiedNode = docNew.importNode(elementNew, true);
docCurrent.getDocumentElement().appendChild(copiedNode);
```

This worked for me.

Regards,